# Equation Comparer Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I want to check whether two equations are logically same or not.

For Example, As like in Excel

```
= (A1+A2)*A3

= A3*A1+A3*A2
```

Above two formulas are logically same. I want to know any algorithms that provides this functionality.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Do you have something already in place e.g. expression tree to parse those from raw string to some class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is build the [expression trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree) and compare them.

If you do that you can detect that the two expressions in the question are equal.

A drawback is that it will not detect equality between:

`k * A1` and `A1 + A1 + ... (k times)`

Comment: Building the expression tree is the first step.  The second step would probably be logical reduction/simplification which would put equivalent expressions into the same form (such as `A*(B+C) ==> A*B + A*C`. Then some kind of rationalization or normalization process that would make the arbitrary ordering of abelian expressions all the same (like `B*A ==> A*B`.

Comment: (A comment which I wish I could make an answer ... oh well.) Solving this problem is interesting and useful, but in general fairly complex. I believe you need to have at least a representation for algebraic expressions (and a means of parsing or otherwise constructing them), and then also an algorithm for determining their equivalence. If only polynomials are considered, I think it might be relatively simple. You can look at Maxima [1] for inspiration; in Maxima the test you want is `is(ratsimp(expr_1 - expr_2) = 0)`. [1] http://maxima.sourceforge.net, http://sourceforge.net/p/maxima